# hiredis async connect with password

Tags: c, authentication, redis, hiredis

I am using [hiredis C library](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) to connect to my redis instance. I am considering changing my redis.conf to enable `requirepass` option. I know that for `redisConnect()` I simply connect to host/port without authentication, and then send the `AUTH mypassword` command using the `redisCommand()` and context. However, how does one do it for `redisAsyncConnect()`? Looking at the source code, the `redisAsyncCommand()` function would fail when asked to send an `AUTH mypassword` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was incorrect in my analysis of `redisAsyncConnect()` function operation. The following code works, with the only caveat that you don't know whether the `AUTH` command succeeded:

```cpp
  redisAsyncContext *async_context = redisAsyncConnect(redis_info.host, redis_info.port);
  if (async_context->err)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error creating async_context: " + async_context->errstr);
  }
  if (0 != strlen(redis_info.passwd))
  {
    if (REDIS_OK != redisAsyncCommand(async_context, NULL, NULL, "AUTH %s", redis_info.passwd))
    {   
      throw std::runtime_error("Error sending AUTH in async_context");
    }   
  }
```